# UNIX Shell script - Saving input file name

Tags: unix, filenames, io-redirection

Let's say I want to run a shell script as follows:

```
./script.sh < in.txt > out.txt
```

**How can I parse the name of the file stdin is redirected to, namely "in.txt" in this example?**

I know that if I have:

```
./script.sh in.txt out.txt
```

I can use the below in the script file to get "in.txt"

```
eval var1="$1"
```

But I can't figure it out for input redirection.
Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, given an externally redirected stdin/stdout, you want  the corresponding files? Do you want a Linux specific solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you don't need to "eval" anything:

```
var1="$1"
```

is enough.

Second: you can't, unless you're happy with "/dev/stdin", "/proc/self/fd/0" or whatever your OS provides; see eg http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sys/doc/lexnames.html -- plan9 needed to **add** fd2path(), because (surprise, surprise) it didn't exist before.

Comment: Your first and second deal with the second and first parts of the question respectively :D  But your points are valid.  And not all files have names.  Think of piped I/O: `command1 ... | command2 ...`.  There isn't really a name (other than the entries in `/proc`) for the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a portable solution, but it works (when the input stream is a regular file) on some systems:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Input file: $( readlink -f /proc/$$/fd/0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
infile=$1
outfile=$2

cat < $1
echo > $2
```

Or if you want to get really fancy, you can change stdin and stdout:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
1<$1
1>$2
echo "test"
```